# Postgis | Problems Reprojecting a Point from UTM ED50 to GEOGRAPHIC ETRS89

Tags: postgis, google-maps, coordinate-system, utm, srid

I've got a POINTS PostGIS table in the 23030 (ED50 UTM 30N) SRID.

I'm having a lot of problems trying to reproject those points from ED50 UTM coordinate system to ETRS89 Geographic (lat/long) coordinate system. The aim is to convert the points for Google Maps.

I take an example point for my tests:

```
x: 499462.1
y: 4799340.56
```

1.- If i just transform the point from UTM (23030) to Geographic lat/long (4230) using the `ST_TRANSFORM("GEOMETRY",4230)` PostGIS function. I get the following coordinates:

```
long: -3.00663639334493
lat: 43.3461345057409
```

You can see in the picture where it is located in Google Maps. It has sense to be located in a different place to the original point, because although being in Geographic projection system it is not in ETRS89/WGS84.

2.- So I reproject the original point first to ETRS89 (nearly the same as Google's WGS84) using `ST_TRANSFORM("GEOMETRY",25830)` and I get the following point:

```
x=499462.124763252
y=4799253.63249274
```

Ok, if I load that point in a GIS, I can see there is a difference between the previous point which is ok as I have changed the SRID.

3.-I thought that if I reprojected the ETRS89 UTM point to ETRS89 lat/long it would be enough for getting the coords valid for Google Maps. The surprise came when I got the same point of the step1!!! (just doing the 4230 transformation)

I used a `ST_TRANSFORM(ST_TRANSFORM("GEOMETRY",25830),4258)` UPDATE query applied to the original point.

[image: https://www.dropbox.com/s/6r82qtimboxnf9z/ejemplo_foros.png]
I don't really know how to solve this mess, I'm really confused.

Comment: From what you described, this looks to be the usual error one expects when converting from one projection system to another, possibly coupled with the [minor inaccuracies of Google Maps](http://hobiger.org/blog/2013/04/20/horizontal-positional-accuracy-of-google-maps/). What are the points you're trying to plot? Which of the points in your picture is the true point of interest?

Comment: What i am trying to plot are house numbers. The point i am trying to plot on google maps is the one in the middle of the picture.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

EPSG:4230 is ED50 lat/long. The proj definition string is:

```
+proj=longlat +ellps=intl +towgs84=-87,-98,-121,0,0,0,0 +no_defs
```

which means that the ED50 ellipsoid is around 100m offset in all three earth-centered directions.

The "true" ETRS89 lat/long EPSG:4258 definition is:

```
+proj=longlat +ellps=GRS80 +towgs84=0,0,0,0,0,0,0 +no_defs
```

which is almost the same as WGS84 definition (see that +towgs84 vaues are all zero).

On Google Maps, you have to enter lat/long always in WGS84. That is why your first points coordinates are misplaced if you enter ED50 values where WGS84 is expected.

I advice you to use a real GIS software like QGIS to view the differences. You can add a Google satellite background with the openlayers plugin.

Comment: Where are the proj definition strings stored? In a PostGIS table?

Comment: Yes, table spatial_ref_sys. You can look it up with pgAdminIII. Or use www.spatialreference.org, but some entries there are outdated.

Comment: Thanks Andre, this finally helped me. I din't notice that in my spatial_ref_sys table i din't have the +towgs84=-87,-98,-121,0,0,0,0 paremeter in the 4230 SRID definiton string. After addin git i just did: `st_x(st_transform(st_transform("GEOMETRY", 4230),4326)) AS long_wgs84_4326, 
st_y(st_transform(st_transform("GEOMETRY", 4230),4326)) AS lat_wgs84_4326,`
to obtain the new wgs84 geographic coords.